# Array initialization by constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have:

```
class first{
   private:
   int *array;

   public:
   first(int x){
     array = new int[x][10];
   }
```

I want to call this class by:

```
first class1 = new first(10);
```

Why it doesn't work ? How to inintialize array by size from constructor ??

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Does it crash?  Where?  Does it not compile?  What is the error you get?  What happened vs. what did you expect?  Details please.

Comment: error: cannot convert 'int (*)[10]' to 'int*' in assignment. How to inintialize 2dimension array by size from constructor ?? I don't want to use vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just this is enough:

```
first class1(10);
```

`new` is for when you're allocating a pointer.

```
first *class1 = new first(10);
```

---

Furthermore, you have an incompatibility here:

```
array = new int[x][10];
```

`array` is an `int*`, but `new int[x][10]` is a 2D array. I'm not sure which one you want.

**For the 1D array:**

```
int *array;
array = new int[x];
```

**For the 2D array:**

```
int (*array)[10];
array = new int[x][10];
```

That said, you might be better off using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

---

**Side Note:** Since you have memory allocation in the constructor, you should also [implement a destructor, copy-constructor, and copy-assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: ...and a copy-assignment operator (per the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)). But unless you particularly want to make things hard for yourself, use `std::vector`.

Comment: I want to initialize 2dimension array by walue from constructor. object shouldn't be an pointer. Vectors are quite another thing. How to do this ?

Comment: Answer updated. Multi-dimension arrays can get very ugly. So I suggest you use `vector<vector<int> > array;` unless you have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

You've indicate that you want a one-dimensional array (`int*`) but attempted to allocate a two-dimensional array (`new [x][10]`).

I'll assume you need one dimension.

The C++ way to do this is with `vector`.

```
#include <vector>

class first{
   private:
   std::vector<int> array;

   public:
   explicit first(int x) : array(x) {
   }
};
```

Comment: I don't need vector type. I'm interested only in array's.